# Memory management in objective C?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have two properties NSString, both of which I have synthesized and are readonly and so I cannot use the property method self. but I though both the passed string most be retained. So, I added retain to retain the properties. But I feel, I will have leaks here since the passed objects are have increased their retain count. But will my properties retain these string without sending message retain.

```
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)passedString1 second:(NSString *)passedString2{
     myString = [passedString1 retain];
     hisString = [passedString2 retain];
}
```

Lets say I have property for array(variable) declared as NSArray and I pass NSDictionary as argument this way;

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text", @"This is some text", nil];
[self setValueForArray:dict];

-(void)setValueForArray:(NSDictionary*)passedDict{
 NSArray *someArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:passedDict];
 if(array!=someArray){
 [array release];
 array = someArray; //I dont think I should retain this property here since it is retained by someArray
 }
}
```

Is this approach correct for NSDictionary and NSArray types.

Comment: Did you try Build and Analyze ?

Comment: Yes, I got some leaks here. I thought these leaks arise as passedString1 and passedString2 are retained. These string are not created  neither  by alloc, copy nor by retain but has been retained in the method above.

Comment: Have you declared the properties only as readonly or as copy or retain  as well ?

Comment: I have declared the properties as retain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `copy` for Strings and release the previous object:

```
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)passedString1 second:(NSString *)passedString2
{
     if (myString != passedString1)
     {
         [myString release]; 
         myString = [passedString1 copy];
     }

     if (hisString != passedString2)
     {
         [hisString release];
         hisString = [passedString2 copy];
     }
}
```

If you need to `release` the Strings that were passed in as parameters, do it in the calling method after calling `setValue:`

Comment: This might fail if ``myString`` happens to be the same object as ``passedString1`` and ``myString`` has a retain count of 1 when you invoke the method. First, it will release ``myString`` (making its retain count zero), and then you are not guaranteed to be able to copy ``passedString1`` because it is the same as ``myString`` and ``myString`` might have been deallocated already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your properties (more precisely, the instance variables corresponding to the properties) will retain the passed strings if you do it this way. However, you must also make sure that the *previous* values are released when the new values are assigned. E.g.,

```
- (void)setValue:(NSString*)passedString1 second:(NSString*)passedString2 {
    if (passedString1 != myString) {
        [myString release];
        myString = [passedString1 retain];
    }
    if (passedString2 != hisString) {
        [hisString release];
        hisString = [passedString2 retain];
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that you release `myString` and `hisString` in the `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want any property to be retained, it is recommended to declare the property as retain and use self. The code above is prone to leaking memory, since you are retaining something in one method, and probably releasing them somewhere else. This will cause much trouble since the two methods are related to each other is someway that is not based on your app logic. (Scary!! You must remember it when you read the code later. Or document it if you want anyone else to look at your code...)

At such a times when I want some variable to be retained and still don't want to use retain property in the header, I create an extension and override that attribute and then use self.

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    SomeClass *someObject; //Example
    ...
}
@property (nonatomic) SomeClass *someObject;
...
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
@interface MyClass () //Category
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeClass *someObject;
@end

@implementation MyClass
...
// Use self.someObject and the object will be retained.
// Release that object in dealloc.
@end
```

EDIT: The same thing goes for NSString as your case. Just replace `retain` by `copy` since its recommended for NSString.

Comment: The new scenario doesn't change anything. The point is you can not rely on someArray being retained somewhere else. If you want to take ownership, take it. Don't expect anything else to retain it. What if that module is changed later? This code will break if you haven't taken the ownership.